# Bound for product of matrices

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

[image]

I am working on the problem above. So far, I have that since M_1 is rank one, the entire product is rank one, so there is one zero eigenvalue. Therefore, we may take the trace of the resulting product to get the value of the other eigenvalue. For the case where lambda is 1, one can prove that [1 1] is always an eigenvector of the product, and the eigenvalue is 1. But I am not sure where to proceed from here.

Comment: What is your question? Especially, what is your programming-related question? .. because that is the only acceptable kind here. Ideally [edit] according to [aks] to put the focus on the programming aspect.

Comment: Your question is better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com.